# User Activity Data from phone with Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to get user activity data (like step count, sleep details, walking distance etc) that is stored on the phone via a Facebook messenger bot?

If the bot cannot retrieve it automatically, it is okay even if there is an option for the user to share that other than manually typing it(like location sharing, which is also not available automatically).

Comment: who down voted, I really appreciate if you can tell me the reason. I did my research and didn't find a way to do this. So looking for some experts to help me if there is an alternative approach or something like that. If the vote is because it sounds like a bad thing to do, thatch an opinion not everyone will agree so that should be a comment not a down vote.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but have answered your question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've requested is currently not possible.

I'm also not sure I would want to share this information with a Facebook Messenger Bot.

Comment: Thank you. I do agree with you that not everyone would like to share that to a bot on Messenger, but some people will if they can share aggregated data anonymously and with a trusted source. I cannot go more in detail, but its a use case we are exploring.